# Regex to strip character

Tags: regex

I have another regex question. Sorry.

Givs a way to strip a character in a match group with regex?

```
Price: 2'765'874.65 
Regex: ([\d']+(?:\.\d{2})?|[\d\.]+(?:,\d{2})?)(?![\d\.,])
Output: 2'765'874.65
Needet Output: 2765874.65
```

That found my price.
But I search a regex ( ot str_replace) that stip ' and show me the Output match group without '

Comment: What language are you using? Use whatever replace/sub function is available in that language.

Comment: Here are samples. The Server of Software is in Java. But I can only use a regex and not more functions like a str replace: https://www.ecodms.de/index.php/de/faq/wissensdatenbank/159-faq-eintraege-ecodms-archiv/ecodms-client/973-tipps-tricks-zur-verwendung-von-regular-expressions-regex-im-vorlagen-designer-von-ecodms

Comment: In the English manual on page 144 you find English sample https://www.ecodms.de/index.php/en/download/manuals/ecodms-archive/ecodms-version-18-09-apu

Comment: It looks like you're just trying to get rid of the character `'`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. I want only my price with the . but without the '

Comment: A group contains only continuous characters. What you want to achieve can't be done with regex alone.

Answer (score 1):

regex:`([\d]+(?=\')*(?:\.\d{2})?|[\d\.]+(?:,\d{2})?)(?![\d\.,])`

output:`2`' `765` ' `874.65`

This way it would only match the numbers [check out](https://regex101.com/r/Gsw60D/1).

The only thing I did was to change `[\d']` To `([\d]+(?=\')*` which I will explain why.

here `(?=\')` is a lookaround, and its type is a **look ahead** look around.

**anything**(?=***s.th***)====> first it checks whether infront of anything is there something ? if the answer is yes .... it matches the pattern **but does not consume that s.th** meaning it only needs to check whether it exists or not but does not shows them in the output.

**in other words, it says look ahead but does not consume it.**

after you got the numbers with grouping them you can get the output.

NOTE: Consider adding which implementation of regex you are using.

Comment: Thank you. My Problem is, the Software is using automaticle use one group and I can't set different group